# postgresql: INSERT INTO ... (SELECT * ...)

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, dblink

I'm not sure if its standard SQL:

```
 INSERT INTO tblA 
 (SELECT id, time 
    FROM tblB 
   WHERE time > 1000)
```

What I'm looking for is: **what if tblA and tblB are in different DB Servers**.

Does PostgreSql gives any utility or has any functionality that will help to use `INSERT query with PGresult struct`

I mean `SELECT id, time FROM tblB ...` will return a `PGresult*` on using `PQexec`. Is it possible to use this struct in another `PQexec` to execute an INSERT command.

EDIT:
If not possible then I would go for extracting the values from PQresult* and create a multiple INSERT statement syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    ('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    ('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy');
```

Is it possible to create a prepared statement out of this!! :(

Comment: I don't know if the INSERT syntax you posted is ANSI, but it is widely supported (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite...).  But the brackets aren't necessary.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

As Henrik wrote you can use dblink to connect remote database and fetch result. For example:

```
psql dbtest
CREATE TABLE tblB (id serial, time integer);
INSERT INTO tblB (time) VALUES (5000), (2000);

psql postgres
CREATE TABLE tblA (id serial, time integer);

INSERT INTO tblA
    SELECT id, time 
    FROM dblink('dbname=dbtest', 'SELECT id, time FROM tblB')
    AS t(id integer, time integer)
    WHERE time > 1000;

TABLE tblA;
 id | time 
----+------
  1 | 5000
  2 | 2000
(2 rows)
```

PostgreSQL has [record](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-pseudo.html) pseudo-type (only for function's argument or result type), which allows you query data from another (unknown) table.

Edit:

You can make it as prepared statement if you want and it works as well:

```
PREPARE migrate_data (integer) AS
INSERT INTO tblA
    SELECT id, time
    FROM dblink('dbname=dbtest', 'SELECT id, time FROM tblB')
    AS t(id integer, time integer)
    WHERE time > $1;

EXECUTE migrate_data(1000);
-- DEALLOCATE migrate_data;
```

Edit (yeah, another):

I just saw your [revised question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086914/postgresql-insert-into-select-ii) (closed as duplicate, or just very similar to this).

If my understanding is correct (postgres has tbla and dbtest has tblb and you want **remote insert with local select**, not **remote select with local insert** as above):

```
psql dbtest

SELECT dblink_exec
(
    'dbname=postgres',
    'INSERT INTO tbla
        SELECT id, time
        FROM dblink
        (
            ''dbname=dbtest'',
            ''SELECT id, time FROM tblb''
        )
        AS t(id integer, time integer)
        WHERE time > 1000;'
);
```

I don't like that nested dblink, but AFAIK I can't reference to tblB in [dblink_exec](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-exec.html) body. Use LIMIT to specify top 20 rows, but I think you need to sort them using ORDER BY clause first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, one more quick question... `INSERT INTO tblA
    SELECT id, time 
    FROM dblink('dbname=dbtest', 'SELECT id, time FROM tblB')
    AS t(id integer, time integer)
    WHERE time > 1000;
` Can I make a prepared statement out of this?

Comment: Hi @grzegorz-szpetkowski,   This logic is giving error : ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.

Comment: What if you have a query with a lot of select statements and want to push the result into a table on another server? Is it possible to *push* the data, say, use dblink on the single "insert into" instead of on each and every select (i.e. *pull*), and execute the query on the "source" server instead of the "target"?

Answer (score 64):

If you want insert into specify column:

```
INSERT INTO table (time)
(SELECT time FROM 
    dblink('dbname=dbtest', 'SELECT time FROM tblB') AS t(time integer) 
    WHERE time > 1000
);
```

Answer (score 25):

This notation (first seen [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3bf1920f$0$201$e4fe514c@newszilla.xs4all.nl)) looks useful too:

```
insert into postagem (
  resumopostagem,
  textopostagem,
  dtliberacaopostagem,
  idmediaimgpostagem,
  idcatolico,
  idminisermao,
  idtipopostagem
) select
  resumominisermao,
  textominisermao,
  diaminisermao,
  idmediaimgminisermao,
  idcatolico ,
  idminisermao,
  1
from
  minisermao
```

Comment: This only works when the tables are in the same database. The Question is regarding copying data from a **table in a different database**.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to create a view that is resolved in another database. This database may be on another server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I did not get how `INSERT INTO ... (SELECT FROM ...)` will work using dblink. What I need is `INSERT INTO ...` to be run in dblink session to other DB Server, but `(SELECT FROM ...)` in my current session.

Comment: You just define tblA as view that is backed by dblink. So inserts, updates, deletes will be done in the other database. dblink is not readonly.

Answer (score 7):

```
insert into TABLENAMEA (A,B,C,D) 
select A::integer,B,C,D from TABLENAMEB
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for **PERFORMANCE**, give where condition inside the db link query.
Otherwise it fetch all data from the foreign table and apply the where condition.

```
INSERT INTO tblA (id,time) 
SELECT id, time FROM  dblink('dbname=dbname port=5432 host=10.10.90.190 user=postgresuser password=pass123', 
'select id, time from tblB  where time>'''||1000||'''')
AS t1(id integer, time integer)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am going to SELECT Databasee_One(10.0.0.10) data from Database_Two (10.0.0.20)

Connect to 10.0.0.20 and create DBLink Extenstion:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Test the connection for Database_One:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('host=10.0.0.10 user=postgres password=dummy dbname=DB_ONE');
```

Create foreign data wrapper and server for global authentication:

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres VALIDATOR postgresql_fdw_validator;
```

You can use this server object for cross database queries:

```
CREATE SERVER dbonepostgres FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres OPTIONS (hostaddr '10.0.0.10', dbname 'DB_ONE');
```

Mapping of user and server:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER dbonepostgres OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'dummy');
```

Test dblink:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dbonepostgres');
```

Import data from 10.0.0.10 into 10.0.0.20

```
INSERT INTO tableA   
  SELECT 
    column1,
    ,column2, 
    ...
  FROM dblink('dbonepostgres', 'SELECT column1, column2, ... from public.tableA')
  AS data(column1 DATATYPE, column2 DATATYPE, ...)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternate solution, without using **`dblink`**.

Suppose B represents the source database and A represents the target database:
Then,

1. Copy table from source DB to target DB:

   ```
   pg_dump -t <source_table> <source_db> | psql <target_db>
   ```
2. Open psql prompt, connect to *target_db*, and use a simple `insert`:

   ```
   psql
   # \c <target_db>;
   # INSERT INTO <target_table>(id, x, y) SELECT id, x, y FROM <source_table>;
   ```
3. At the end, delete the copy of *source_table* that you created in *target_table*.

   ```
   # DROP TABLE <source_table>;
   ```