# Postgres insert from select statement with multiple values

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083132/postgresql-insert-into-select) but all answers seem to provide a solution for when there is a single field. I need to additionally set one more field while inserting. I tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y)
select id
FROM boo b1, 3
```

I get

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "3"

How can I use the `select` AND another value to `INSERT INTO` foo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y)
SELECT b1.id, 3
FROM boo b1;
```

A literal value must go into the `SELECT` clause, it's not another table in the `FROM` clause. What can also work is

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y)
VALUES
  ( (SELECT b1.id FROM boo b1 WHERE …), 3 );
```

or

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y)
SELECT (SELECT b1.id FROM boo b1 WHERE …), 3;
```

but these are only valid if the inner `SELECT` (a subquery) returns exactly one value, using an appropriate `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The query ran but apart from this issue, I got `You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`. Because `x` column is integer type and as far as I understand `SELECT b1.id FROM boo b1` is treated as record type. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Silidrone `(SELECT b1.id FROM boo b1)` should not be treated as a record, it returns a single integer column. Which of the three queries gave that error?

Comment: The second one. The first one worked without a problem.

Comment: @Silidrone Ah, thanks, you're totally right - that's one pair of parenthesis too much. Repaired now ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa223ea0b261493698bc7fa6d4275609)). I guess I've used `SELECT … FROM (VALUES (…), (…)) x` too often.