# PostgreSQL- If data in table, delete for stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure, which I call with `CALL pr_calc_quarter(2,2022)`, that insert data into a table `erp.tb_quarter` from a query.
I need to add code to check that if there is already data in the table, to delete it before inserting new values.

I was thinking of inserting the code at the beggining or before the insert into, but I don't know
how to check if there is already data on the table.

I just need how to do the check, no need for working demo :). I don't know if trigger before insert could work here with parameters in the procedure.

The procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter( trimestre INT , anio INT ) AS $$
DECLARE
    v_cust_no CHARACTER(5);
    v_iva_percent INT;
    v_amount REAL;
BEGIN
        FOR trimestre, anio, v_cust_no, v_iva_percent, v_amount IN
            SELECT
                EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM i.last_update_date) AS quarter,
                EXTRACT(year FROM i.last_update_date)  AS year,
                c.cust_no,
                round((i.iva_amount * 100 / net_amount)::numeric,0) AS iva_percent,
                SUM(i.iva_amount) AS amount
            FROM erp.tb_customer c JOIN erp.tb_invoice i ON i.cust_no = c. cust_no
            WHERE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM i.last_update_date) = trimestre AND EXTRACT(year FROM i.last_update_date) = anio
            GROUP BY iva_percent, c.cust_no, year, quarter
            ORDER BY c.cust_no, iva_percent, amount
            LOOP
            INSERT INTO erp.tb_quarter
            VALUES (trimestre, anio, v_cust_no, v_iva_percent, v_amount);
            END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to delete all data from table then just do always

```sql
truncate erp.tb_quarter;
```

place it in next line after `BEGIN`

If you want to delete only data from calculated range do `delete` with proper `where`

Additionaly in place of loop you can just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` construction

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083132/postgresql-insert-into-select)

Comment: Hi, I want that always that I call this procedure, if there is data: delete and then insert. If no data, just insert.  Could you explain me where should I put this code? Just a small preview of how the code would look like :) Thanks!!!

Comment: `truncate` is fastest way to empty table, no need to do additional check if you always want to delete all data.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, I just need to put the truncate before the insert into in the loop??

Comment: Yes. Additionally you can replace loop with `Insert into ... select from` construction

Comment: So, no need really to loop? Thx

Comment: No need for loop. I am still not convinced that all data should be deleted if this procedure can be launched at the same moment for different periods by different people.